# Displaying a long horizontal and vertical list

Tags: android, android-listview, user-experience

I want to create a smartphone app (Android for starters) which in its base core of data displaying, will have a list of many titles in a long header (long horizontal) and also displays many items (long vertical).

I guess I can avoid the long vertical by restricting the number of items in a page, but what is a proper way to display a long horizontal list on a smartphone screen? Should it be enough to have horizontal scrolling? should I force a landscape view?

Please notice I'm not asking about the technical stuff of HOW to create it, but rather more about the UX point of view of the matter.

Comment: `Should it be enough to have horizontal scrolling? should I force a landscape view?` ... or **both**.

Comment: I find it odd forcing landscape view. Portrait doesn't seem like a problem but landscape seems strange.

Comment: Why? it's enough to turn your device 90°. And it's the natural orientation on tablets...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Set horizontal view for your view from manifest file.
wrap your view layout   with horizontal scroll.
May be it would be help to you.
If you share your code then you get more supportive answer.

Comment: I didn't start anything yet. This is a pre implementation question to determine the best way of making the app. Also, I find it odd forcing landscape view. Portrait doesn't seem like a problem but landscape seems strange.